# What is the proper term for the "n" and "r" in the combination/permutation (nCr, nPr) functions?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, terminology, convention

Just like when we add, the parameters are called "addends", and how division has a "dividend", "divisor", "quotient", and "remainder", what is the conventional name for the *n* and *r* in combinatorics functions *nCr* and *nPr*?

Not looking for a definition (eg, the number of items chosen as a subset from all the choices).  Looking for the precise term.

Intuitively I might call the *r* a "selector", but I have no idea if that's the right term.

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: nice one !
 let's take something simpler, $1 + x + x^2+...+ x^k+...+x^n $, then n is called degree. What's the name of k ?

Comment: @Boyku exponent or power?

Comment: Choosing is subtraction. Given the combinatorial context, the subtraction becomes much much more dificult https://combinatorics.fandom.com/wiki/Subtraction_Tables : minuend and subtrahend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In section 5.1 *Basic Identities* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik the authors introduce binomial coefficients and designate $n$ and $r$
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}={}_{n}C_{r}
\end{align*}
*upper index* and *lower index*.

Answer (score 5):

These are called indices of the symbol for the combinatorial quantity. Binomial coefficients are usually written using the notation $\binom nk$, in which one can refer to $n$ as the upper index and $k$ as the lower index. If a number like a Stirling number is written like $s(n,k)$ one could call them first and second indices. As for notations in which numbers are written around a central letter in all kinds of directions like the planets of Jupiter, just say no.